# Transposing row vector X to get compatible dimensions warning in Scilab

Tags: scilab

I am learning to use Scilab, I tried plotting a function which I know have a discontinuity at a certain value but the plot I got had a non expectable behavior so I tried to plot a very well known function "y=1/x".

I created the "x" vector

```
x=[-10:1:10];
```

Then created the "y" function

```
y=1/x;
```

And then used the plot command

```
plot(x,y)
```

I got the following warning

> WARNING: Transposing row vector X to get compatible dimensions

And my plot is a straight line, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: If the answer answers your question, please don't forget to accept it (there's a button for that) to signal that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take care: 1/x compute some thing like 1*pinv(x) not the array [1/x(1),1/x(2),...]. to obtain the previous result use 1 ./x for element wise disvision.

Comment: Actually that solved my problem, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Well, try typing `x` and `y` into the consol, to see, how your variables look like:

```
-->x
 x  =


         column  1 to 12

  - 10.  - 9.  - 8.  - 7.  - 6.  - 5.  - 4.  - 3.  - 2.  - 1.    0.    1.  

         column 13 to 21

    2.    3.    4.    5.    6.    7.    8.    9.    10.  

-->y
 y  =

  - 0.0129870  
  - 0.0116883  
  - 0.0103896  
  - 0.0090909  
  - 0.0077922  
  - 0.0064935  
  - 0.0051948  
  - 0.0038961  
  - 0.0025974  
  - 0.0012987  
    0.         
    0.0012987  
    0.0025974  
    0.0038961  
    0.0051948  
    0.0064935  
    0.0077922  
    0.0090909  
    0.0103896  
    0.0116883  
    0.0129870
```

So `x` is a row array, and `y` is a column array, that's why scilab is complaining about incompatible dimensions. To remove the warning, you must transpose one of your arrays, to make them identical in dimensions. You can do it many places, e.g:

```
y=1/x';
```

or

```
plot(x',y);
```

or

```
plot(x,y');
```

Note: in Scilab 5.4.x and earlier versions there was no such warning, Scilab silently transposed one of the arrays.